# Laptop always indicates it is charging

Tags: battery

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a XPS 13 9350 (0704). The laptop always indicates that it is charging even when it is unplugged. How do I address this?

For those familiar with the LED display on the bottom of the XPS 13 near the touchpad, that is also lit up as when the laptop charges (this LED turns orange if the computer falls below a certain battery percentage as well).

Answer (score 0):

technically if it is plugged in and on it is always charging. If you are stating that even unplugged the icon shows charging, that is just a minor glitch in the icon itself. I had that happen on Ubuntu 13.10 i think on my laptop. Didn't cause any issues, but i do think they had a fix for it then if I remember right.